# Error using ^ Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a problem running this code which gives me this error

> Error using  ^  Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix. To
>   compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.
>
> Error in cal_path (line 149)
>   f=z-(2*(1+sqrt(1-Cx^2*y^2))*(Cx*x^2+Cy*y^2)-Cx*Cy^2*(x^2+y^2)*y^2)./(1+sqrt(1-Cx^2*y^2))*((1+sqrt(1-Cx^2*y^2))...

This is my code

```
 Cx=1/25;              
 Cy=1/10

 syms x y z
 f=z-(2*(1+sqrt(1-Cx^2*y^2))*(Cx*x^2+Cy*y^2)-Cx*Cy^2*(x^2+y^2)*y^2)./(1+sqrt(1- Cx^2*y^2))*((1+sqrt(1-Cx^2*y^2))+sqrt((1+sqrt(1-Cx^2*y^2))^2-Cx*(2*1+sqrt(1-Cx^2*y^2)*(Cx*x^2+Cy*y^2)-Cx*Cy^2*(x^2+y^2)*y^2)));
 %the function of the surface F(x,y,z)=0%

 diff(f,x); % calculate the differential of x
 diff(f,y); % calculate the differential of y
 diff(f,z); % calculate the differential of z
```

Comment: When I dump your code in my MATLAB, I get no error. Somehow your MATLAB is trying to compute `f` numerically, which means you've either forgotten `syms x y z` in your *real* code, or something else is going on...

Comment: If you really get this error when running the code, please try to restart Matlab. Perhaps you did something strange in the session that interferes with this calculation.